# Is there something like Stellarium but with proper moving around?

Tags: simulation, astronomy

Stellarium is a realistic night sky simulator. Basically, a fixed imagined camera is placed on the surface of Earth at a given GPS coordinate and date/time, and then you get to see the Sun, Moon and all the other objects on the sky, including the stars, move just as they would have done if you had been standing on that position at that time. You can rewind, fast-forward, etc., to see how the sky changes based on the clock and date.

Although I like the idea of the program, it has one major flaw: the camera is fixed to the North, and although I think you can change the rotation or exact position that the camera "looks at", it's far from intuitive and smooth.

I find myself wanting Stellarium, but with "first-person shooter" controls. That is, walk/strafe around with WASD and then freely look with the mouse. This would be much better than the fixed camera facing North and just changing the "field of view", which just confuses me. I wish to "stand there" like I would in reality and move my "head" to the compass direction that I want to look at, fast-forwarding to the next point of interest and looking straight up to see where the Sun is and how its light affects the environment in terms of glow/shine/shadows, etc.

I'd really love a more interactive Stellarium, which looks like a realistic video game but has no "game" elements, and is all about the Sun and the Moon and their positions on the sky as seen from Earth, and the way they affect the lighting and everything.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Please specify the Operating System. Do so by [editing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/76493/edit) your original post.

Comment: And while on it, also include your price limit (how much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid products).